# How to recieve a http request in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I setup a chrome extension to recieve http request from **outside the browser ?**

What I would like to do , is send a http request from my local machine / app to the chrome extension. So the app can communicate / send commands to the extension.

Basicly turn the extension into a server ? So it would have local adress 127.0.0.1 and a port I can target ?

How to aproach this ?

Thanks

Comment: An extension can 1) open a WebSocket to your local web server, 2) or use nativeMessaging API.

Comment: Thanks will take a look. Both are unfamiliar to me.